# Where to get Developer Image for 7.2 Xcode

Tags: xcode

Looking for a Developer Image for my iPhone 5s so I'm able to run an app. I believe my iPhone has the 12.1 OS and I'm currently running Yosemite 10.10.5 on my Macbook. I tried 7.3 Xcode and it won't run. Can't run newer versions of Xcode either due to my OS. I read that I can download Xcode 10 and then copy the developer files over, but I wasn't able to extract the .xip files.

Answer (score 0):

It is available for registered Apple Developers on [Apple's Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/):

[image: image of listing]

You can find all old Xcode versions there.

Comment: I do have that version, but I need the developer image for the newer OS. The 7.2 only goes up to the 9.2 OS.

Comment: Sorry, I got your question wrong. So you want to use a new iOS simulator in an old Xcode? I do not know if this is going to work.

Comment: No problem and yes that is correct. From what I've read people have been doing this with slightly newer versions of Xcode. But for whatever reason I can't extract the xip file and have tried a couple different extractors. Every time I get an error.